# How to set canonical url for homepage in Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2, layout, error

I have tried setting below code but i get the below error.

```
<head>
    <link rel="canonical" src="https://www.example.com/" src_type="url"/>
</head>
```

> Please correct the XML data and try again. Element 'head': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( referenceContainer, container, update, move ). Line: 1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set homepage canonical url with theme:

> 1. app/design/frontend/[VendorName]/[themename]/Magento_Cms/layout/cms_index_index.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link rel="canonical" src="https://www.example.com" src_type="url" />
    </head>
</page>
```

OR

Set homepage canonical url with module:

> 1. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/registration.php

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    '[VendorName]_[ModuleName]',
    __DIR__
);
```

> 2. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/etc/module.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="[VendorName]_[ModuleName]" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

> 3. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/view/frontend/layout/cms_index_index.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link rel="canonical" src="https://www.example.com" src_type="url" />
    </head>
</page>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add the additions header as below inside body tag to the respective layout XML file, In your case `cms_index_index.xml` is the file.

```
<referenceContainer name="head.additional">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="head.rel.canonical" template="Vensdor_Module::template.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
```

In the **template.phtml** you can add canonical.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in the admin part

Goto Content > Design > Select the homepage ( per shop if you've more than one )
and Open up Design then in the block Layout Update xml write

```
> <head>
>       <link rel="canonical" src="<website home page adress>" src_type="url"/>   
> </head>
```

Reindex && clear cache

Comment: this did not work